# Migrating ObservableObject and @Published Tests to Swift’s New @Observable Macro

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject

I have just migrated from using `ObservableObject` and the `@Published` property wrapper to the new `@Observable` macro in Swift. I am wondering how I can rewrite these kind of tests. Please keep in mind that my tests cover arbitrarily complex cases with asynchronous behavior, and this is just an oversimplified example.

```swift
func testVoiceListUpdates() {
    let initialExpectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Voice list should be empty initially")
    let firstExpectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "First voice should be added")
    let secondExpectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Second voice should be added")

    let viewModel = MyViewModel()

    let firstVoice = Voice.fixture()
    let secondVoice = Voice.fixture()

    viewModel.$voiceList
        .sink { newValue in
            switch newValue.count {
            case 0:
                initialExpectation.fulfill()
            case 1:
                if newValue.first == firstVoice {
                    firstExpectation.fulfill()
                    viewModel.addVoice(secondVoice)
                }
            case 2:
                if newValue.last == secondVoice {
                    secondExpectation.fulfill()
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)

    viewModel.addVoice(firstVoice)
    
    wait(for: [initialExpectation, firstExpectation, secondExpectation], timeout: 1)
}
```

The point is that in the MVVM architecture all of the logic is in the ViewModel, and all of the visible behavior can be fully tested by just testing the ViewModels. How are we supposed to do this with the new `@Observable` macro? Any suggestions and best practices would be appreciated.

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing, if it can be "arbitrarily complex". I don't think it would be more convenient to do this with Observation, at least for now.

Comment: If the function is synchronous just put the check on the other side no expectation needed. If it isn’t, make it with async/await

Comment: Can someone please create the @Observable tag for this question?

Comment: You can’t add a tag with an @ symbol that is for tagging people

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [withObservationTracking(_:onChange:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/observation/withobservationtracking(_:onchange:)) function, and your test would change to something like this:

```swift
func testVoicePropertyChange() {
    let viewModel = MyViewModel()
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Voice property should change")
    let voice = Voice.fixture()

    @Sendable func observe() {
        withObservationTracking {
            if viewModel.voice == voice {
                expectation.fulfill()
            }
        } onChange: {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: observe)
        }
    }
    observe()

    viewModel.updateVoiceProperty(with: voice)

    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1)
}
```

Any properties accessed in the first closure passed to `withObservationTracking` will result in the `onChange` closure being executed, where you can schedule another observation (as the `onChange` closure is called only once).

This enables monitoring multiple properties, allowing more complex scenarios, for example:

```swift
withObservationTracking {
    if viewModel.voice == voice {
        expectation.fulfill()
    }
    if viewModel.volume == 15 {
        volumeExpectation.fulfill()
    }
} onChange: {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: observe)
}
```

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer.
It works perfectly and doesn't require any change in the view model.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing a Dedicated Testing `CurrentValueSubject` when using `@Observable`

A simple solution would be to introduce a `testVoiceListSubject` in our ViewModel to observe changes in the `voiceList` property. Below is how we can adjust our ViewModel and test class accordingly:

1. **Modify our ViewModel**:

```swift
@Observable
class MyViewModel {
    private(set) var testVoiceListSubject = CurrentValueSubject<[Voice], Never>([])
    
    var voiceList: [Voice] = [] {
        didSet {
            testVoiceListSubject.send(voiceList)
        }
    }
    
    func addVoice(_ voice: Voice) {
        voiceList.append(voice)
    }
}
```

2. **Update Our Test Method**:

```swift
func testVoiceListUpdates() {
    let initialExpectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Voice list should be empty initially")
    let firstExpectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "First voice should be added")
    let secondExpectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Second voice should be added")
    
    let viewModel = MyViewModel()
    
    let firstVoice = Voice.fixture()
    let secondVoice = Voice.fixture()

    viewModel.testVoiceListSubject
        .sink { newValue in
            switch newValue.count {
            case 0:
                initialExpectation.fulfill()
            case 1:
                if newValue.first == firstVoice {
                    firstExpectation.fulfill()
                    viewModel.addVoice(secondVoice)
                }
            case 2:
                if newValue.last == secondVoice {
                    secondExpectation.fulfill()
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)

    viewModel.addVoice(firstVoice)

    wait(for: [initialExpectation, firstExpectation, secondExpectation], timeout: 1)
}
```

This approach works great because we get all the simplicity and performance benefits from the new `@Observable` macro, since this `CurrentValueSubject` doesn't have any side effects like `@Published` had, and it requires minimal setup. We assume that someday Apple will add a way to listen to properties in classes that use the `@Observable` macro directly, which could provide a more integrated solution. For now, this method allows us to retain the testability of our ViewModel while adapting to the new `@Observable` macro, ensuring a smooth transition as we leverage the new features in Swift.

Comment: This pollutes the interface of the view model, as the publisher is added solely for unit testing, it has no other means besides that. It's also not scalable, as each property will need a dedicated publisher.

Comment: Since only the properties where the tests require testing of an asynchronous sequence require this set up, it’s not all properties but rather a very small number. I agree, that the pollution of the interface is not pretty. Then again, the naming makes it clear that it’s part of the testing interface and the pollution is rather minimal. It’s probably also just a temporary solution until Apple adds such basic functionality.